# ModRewrite .htaccess / SEO URLs syntax

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to re-use some .htaccess code on a new site/server and it doesn't work correctly.  I'm not an expert with URL rewriting so would appreciate it if anyone can see if my syntax is incorrect or if there is something else I need to check server side.

I am using the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# News Pages
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php
RewriteRule ^news/(.*?)/$ /news.php?article=$1
```

It works for the 1st level, /news/ but /news/article-1/ just loads the /news/ (news.php) overview page.  /news.php?article=article-1 works correctly.

Server is running Apache 2.2.9 and PHP is in CGI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try it such way:

```
    RewriteRule ^news/(.*?)/?$ /news.php?article=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^news/?$ /news.php [L]
```

[L] in the end of instruction stops server cheacking of other instructions, if current one match.

So you write more specific ahead of more general.

If your rules work correctly being the only one in the .htaccess, then such organisation of them can help.

/? - this means that / at the end can absent or present

Comment: Still does the same, reading some of the Related questions, PHP is running in CGI mode if that is relevant?

Comment: Added /? - read in my answer. + I'd like to hear results of testing your rules when they are alone in file: what work and what not. Then it will be more easy to combine them together.